# How to assign stdin arguments to variables in BASH from Pipe

Tags: bash, stdin

**What I'm trying:**

I'm trying to assign args to a variable if it is from Pipe

**Expected:**

What should I do inside my script to assign the arguments to variables so that they look like this?

```
if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
    option1="one"
    option2="two"
    option3="three"
    echo "$option1" "$option2" "$option3"
else
    echo "no input"
fi
```

**Input:** `echo one two three | ./myscript`
**Output:** `one two three`

**Question Update:**
I need all the arguments presented before the |(pipe) as just string input to my script.
It should not check for existence or execute the binary(here the binary is `echo`) present before the |(pipe).

**Input:** `echo one two three | ./myscript`
**Output:** `echo one two`

Comment: My answer to [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/600253/why-is-xargs-necessary/600273#600273) might help clarify the difference between arguments (what you're thinking of) and input via STDIN (which is what your script is actually getting).

Answer (score 3):

The words `one`, `two`, `three` in `echo one two three | ./myscript` are arguments of `echo`; but to `./myscript` they are only input, not arguments.

#### Reading "arguments" from stdin

To read each word into its own variable use

```
if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
    read -r option1 option2 option3 
    echo "$option1" "$option2" "$option3"
else
    echo "no input"
fi
```

If you want to allow an arbitrary number of words, use an array.
`read -ra myArray` reads all words from a single line into an array.
`mapfile -t myArray` reads all lines into an array.
`read -rd '' -a myArray` reads all words from all lines into an array.

To access the words in the array, use `${myArray[0]}`, `${myArray[1]}`, ..., `${myArray[${#myArray[@]}-1]}`.

#### Using actual arguments

Instead of parsing stdin it might be better to use actual arguments. To do so, execute your script like `./myscript one two three`. Then access the arguments using positional parameters:

```
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
   echo "no arguments"
else
   echo "The arguments are $1 $2 $3 ..."
fi
```

For an arbitrary number of arguments check out [`shift`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#shift) and `$@`.

Comment: Am I allowed a question? When you execute `echo one two three | ./myscript` the output of `echo` isn't the 1st argument of `myscript`?

Comment: @Themelis Exactly. `one` would only be an argument if you executed `./myscript one`. With `echo one | ./myscript` it is only input.

Comment: I have one more doubt which I added in "Question Update:"

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN To me it seems like your update only clarified that you want `echo a b c | script` instead of `script a b c`. The only action I could take from there would be to remove the last half of my answer. But I have nothing to add. If you are still asking about a detail I didn't mention, please ask about it in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably simply use `xargs` instead. But what you ask isn't hard to do *per se.*

```sh
if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
    read -r option1 option2 option3
    echo "$option1" "$option2" "$option3"
else
    echo "no input"
fi
```

With `xargs`, this would look like

```sh
option1=$1
option2=$2
option3=$3
```

and then you'd just run it with

```sh
echo first second third |
xargs ./yourscript
```